# VC++ wcscpy_s randomly assert on "Buffer is too small"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

You can see the parameter sent to the function does not exceed the buffer size from the code below.

This problem happened randomly, and only happened in debug build.

```
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>

#define BUF_SZ 32

int main()
{
  wchar_t src[BUF_SZ]{};
  bool running = true;
  std::thread th([&] {
    for (double g = 0; g < 100000; g += .1)
    {
      std::wstringstream ws;
      ws << g;
      wcscpy_s(src, BUF_SZ, ws.str().c_str());
    }
    running = false;
  });

  wchar_t dst[BUF_SZ]{};
  while (running)
    wcscpy_s(dst, src);  // assert on "Buffer is too small" randomly

  th.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202105/discussion-on-question-by-eihero-vc-wcscpy-s-randomly-assert-on-buffer-is-too).

Comment: With optimization turned to high I don't think your code will ever exit. That running variable needs to be made std::atomic. As it is the optimizer won't include it as it has no visible effect in each thread it exists in.

Comment: @ZanLynx, the program do exit, it's a simple SRSW(single reader single writer) lock-free demonstration.

Comment: It's more than lock-free, it's boolean read-free. Look at https://godbolt.org/z/qgsm7r and line 249 in the assembly output. Yes, I modified the code to play with it and de-lambda'd it, if that's a word. But as soon as I define wcscpy_s as an inline function the compiler "helpfully" removes the "useless" read of the `running` boolean.

Comment: @ZanLynx, thanks to your time, but `running` is not the problem. If it runs as you said, it would sound like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @eihero It is not a problem for your program *at the moment* because you do operations outside of the compiler's view, in other libraries. If that code ever becomes visible to the compiler then it defintely will. You can *see it being done* in that godbolt example. It simply loops over the inline wcscpy_s function without ever reading `running`. I am just trying to help you for the future here.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. Steve Wishnousky from MSFT VC++ team, here is the complete explanation of the problem.

> Wcscpy_s does not operate atomically on the buffers and will only work
>   correctly if the buffers do not change contents during the runtime of
>   wcscpy_s.
>
> Another thing to note is that in Debug mode, the wcscpy_s function
>   will fill the rest of the buffer in with a debug mark (0xFE) to
>   indicate that the data there is now invalid to assume it's contents,
>   in order to detect potential runtime errors.
>
> The error happens differently every time of course, but lets assume
>   this error happens when src=1269.9 and wcscpy_s(dst, src) is called.
>   The actual contents of src is: "1 2 6 9 . 9 null 0xfe 0xfe ...".
>   wcscpy_s copies over the 1269.9 but as it's about to read the null,
>   the other wcscpy_s just wrote a new value to src so it's now: "1 2 7 0
>   null 0xfe 0xfe ...". Instead of reading the null corresponding from
>   the previous src, it reads the 0xfe, so it thinks this is a real
>   character. Since there is no null terminator until we reach the end of
>   the buffer, the Debug runtime asserts that the buffer was too small
>   for the input.
>
> In the Release build, the 0xFE debug marks aren't placed in the
>   buffer, so it will eventually find a null character. You can also
>   disable the debug marks by calling _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetdebugfillthreshold?view=vs-2019.
>
> Note that the Debug marks are actually catching a real correctness
>   problem here though. This "buffer changed during wcscpy_s" issue could
>   happen for any value. For example, if src=1269.9, wcscpy_s could copy
>   over the 126, but then as it's about to read the 9, src is updated to
>   1270 and the value that would end up in dest would be "1260".

Answer (score 0):

Since the string copy will need to copy "src" characters and a terminating null character you'll need to provide a buffer which is at least one character bigger than sizeof "src".

I suggest you could try to use:

```
    wcscpy_s(dst, sizeof src+1, src);
```

Comment: The src buffer is initialized and filled with 0, also the converted string size of g never exceed 7, it is always null terminated at any time.

Comment: wcscpy_s in debug mode has checked that the length specified (strlen(name) is not enough to fit the name + the terminating \0, so it asserts.
If dest or src is a null pointer, or if the destination string size dest_size is too small, the invalid parameter handler is invoked.
In C++, use of these functions is simplified by template overloads that can infer buffer length automatically so that you don't have to specify a size argument, and they can automatically replace older, less-secure functions with their newer, more secure counterparts.

Comment: I get your point but it's not the problem. As I had said, the buffer has 32 elements and the converted string never exceed 7, strlen(name) should be always enough to fit the name + the terminating \0. 

The code is only for demonstration. It's a simple SRSW(single reader, single writer) problem, which the reader only care about get the latest data.

Hope you can report this problem to Visual C++ team. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you could post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help.

Comment: I had post the solution from MSFT VC++ team, thanks to your information.